# How to re-render a particular row in react-native flatList on state/props changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new to react-native and redux.I have a flatList to show a list details from an api call using redux.Whenever I try to edit/delete a list item,flatList does not re-render upon the changes.

I have tried with extraData props also,but nothing worked out.Seriously looking for help!!

```
 <FlatList
                data={this.state.vacationsDataSource}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                extraData={this.props.Vacations_reducer.vacationsData}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <View style={styles.mainView_contact}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                      <View style={styles.Txt_hight}>
                        <Text style={styles.SecName}>Start date </Text>
                      </View>
                      <View>
                        <Text style={styles.name2}>
                          {dateFormat(item.vacationFrom, "mmmm dS, yyyy")}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>
```

Here is my componentWillRecieveProps method,

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.Vacations_reducer.vacationsData != nextProps.Vacations_reducer.vacationsData) {
      this.setState({
        vacationsDataSource: nextProps.Vacations_reducer.vacationsData
      });
    }
  }
```

My componentDidMount,

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRenderFetchVacations().then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        vacationsDataSource: this.props.Vacations_reducer.vacationsData
      });
    });
    Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", this._keyboardDidShow);
    Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", this._keyboardDidHide);
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }
```

And my reducer looks like this,

```
const VacationDetailReducer = (state = DEFAULT_STATE_VAC, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case VAC_FETCH_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };

    case VAC_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        vacationsData: action.vacationsData
      };

    case VAC_FETCH_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        vacationsData: action.vacationsData
      };
case ADD_VAC_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        //isLoading: false,
        addVacationData: action.addVacationData
      };

    case ADD_VAC_FETCH_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        //isLoading: false,
        addVacationData: action.addVacationData
      };

    case UPDATE_VAC_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        //isLoading: false,
        updateVacationData: action.updateVacationData
      };

    case UPDATE_VAC_FETCH_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        //isLoading: false,
        updateVacationData: action.updateVacationData
      };

    case DELETE_VAC_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        //isLoading: false,
        deleteVacationData: action.deleteVacationData
      };

    case DELETE_VAC_FETCH_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        //isLoading: false,
        deleteVacationData: action.deleteVacationData
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default VacationDetailReducer;
```

Comment: I actually don't see the code you do 'Edit' a single row. Basically once you identify the code, you need to make sure your list get assigned again, ex. `[...items]`. Not just `item.abc = 123`. Because the items reference doesn't get refreshed, which won't trigger the render via state change.

Comment: edit functionality is also based on api calls,so I haven't added the codes here.I just wanted to know how to re-render the flatList based on update/delete. Could you explain a bit more in detail ? @windmaomao

Answer (score 0):

I think ComponentWillReceiveProps doesn't get any updated props, so it doesn't call the setState method and thus the FlatList not rendered again. You need to check if the ComponentWillReceiveProps is again called or not. Just add a console or alert after the if condition.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (this.props.Vacations_reducer.vacationsData != nextProps.Vacations_reducer.vacationsData) {
   console.log("Hello")
   this.setState({
     vacationsDataSource: nextProps.Vacations_reducer.vacationsData
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: it comes inside componentwillRecieveProps method and sets the new data to state,but still flatlist is not re-rendered.

Comment: data should be an array in FlatList. Please update data to an array from an object and check again.